# Telling Dragon NaturallySpeaking not to consider the next word as a command

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

From time to time, I want to dictate a single word that happens to also be a voice command. Is there any way to tell Dragon NaturallySpeaking not to consider the next word as a command, without having to switch the dictation mode?

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to go about this without changing the Mode. **Word** is used as a placeholder for the actual command/word in this answer.

1. Just say "**word** space bar". It will insert a space after the word without triggering the command.
2. Or use a spoken form for the word, e.g. "**word** as word".
   [image]
3. Or alter the command to present you with a choice between the word and the command. This requires some fairly Advanced Scripting.
4. Just type the word.